# Save or Cancel edits in vue/vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, v-model

I have a component which handles some user data, like `firstName`, `lastName` etc. through inputs (text fields, custom selects etc.)

There's a vuex store storing this data, and component fields are binded with `v-model` to it.

I want these fields to be editable, but the moment user starts editing one of the fields, buttons `Save` and `Cancel` should appear.

Clicking `Save` button applies the changes, and clicking `Cancel` should revert all fields to the state they were in before editing started.

I'm wondering if there's any best practice/pattern for this task?

Comment: what can you do is have an object(data) for your form inputs, getter(mapGetters) and variable to determine if there's changes, then you can add a watcher for the form object. You'll then add a condition in the watcher which will compare the form object to the getter. Lastly, If there's changes you'll set the variable for changes to true.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's best practice, but I can explain how I've handled something similar. I have 2 properties, `formFieldsModified` and `formFieldsInitialState`.

```
data() {
    return {
        formFieldsModified: false,
        formFieldsInitialState: {}
    }
}
```

When the component is mounted/created I call a method called `setFormFieldsInitialState`.

```
created: function () {
    this.$store.dispatch('LOAD_USER').then((item) => {
        this.setFormFieldsInitialState()
    });
}
```

This is using lodash to create a deep clone of the object so I can compare against the current `user` object and see if anything has changed.

```
setFormFieldsInitialState() {
    this.formFieldsInitialState = _.cloneDeep(this.user)
    this.formFieldsModified = false;
}
```

Then you can watch for changes to the model, let's say it's called `user`.

```
watch: {
    'user': {
        handler: function (val) {
            this.formFieldsModified = (!_.isEqual(val, this.formFieldsInitialState)) ? true : false;
        },
        deep: true
    }
}
```

Now you can use `this.formFieldsModified` to toggle the visibility of your buttons depending on whether or not any of the form fields have been modified.

As far as the cancel/save actions – you will have to have a different method that actually updates your store, so unless the user clicks the save button and dispatches an action that updates the store, nothing will happen. You can then use the `formFieldsInitialState` object that was created to revert any values back to what they originally were.

Comment: Fwiw: same approach here

Answer (score 0):

I used to approach my components this way, but I've begun to think the complication may be that this approach may mix concerns. I'm facing a similar issue today with a component that is tracking a multiple selection checkbox. I think perhaps the *child component* should be dumb--render options & communicate selections. Then whatever is managing the data (in your case vuex, in my case a parent component) should be deciding what business rules say to do with that data.

So my solution is similar to Charlie's but instead of having the child component duplicate data into a temporary / initial state on mount; your vuex (in my case my parent component) would manage the two sets of data (formFieldsSaved and formFieldsWorking) and would be responsible for committing the working set to overwrite the Saved values on some action. I think it may be conceptually a cleaner approach which is reinforced by being able to avoid mounting and creating data properties which shadow a v-model prop. So a simple flow map:

```
// approach 1
controller
   - passes final values into prop of
child component
   - accepts prop.values
   - initializes with data.modifiedValues = null
   - on mount: copy prop.values into data.modified
   - selections use data.modified as v-models
   - on commit, communicate data.modified up w event
controller
   - hear event
   - modify values
```

vs

```
// approach 2
controller
   - manages savedValues, workingValues, and interactions between them
child component
   - accepts prop.values (in this case workingValues)
   - onChange sends signal up to 
controller
   - hear event
   - modify workingValues
   - commit workingValues to savedValues whenever the controller wants (probably an "update" event from the form)
   - commit savedValues back to working values whenever the controller wants (probably a "reset" even from the form)
```

That's just my current approach. I thought I'd throw it in there as an alternative. But I'd be interested to see what other devs think, as this is a common situation.